# How do I refresh Gnome 3 applications

Tags: desktop, gnome3

I just added and modified a `.desktop` file in my `/home/user/.local/share/applications` folder.

Is there any way to refresh the icon and caption in the list of applications without logging out?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You can restart the `gnome-shell` by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and then typing in either "*restart*" or just "*r*" and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Otherwise I've noticed that it automatically refreshes `.desktop` files after waiting a little while.

Comment: Well, that alt-f2 really made is so I didn't even need to do it.  and I did notice that it was refreshing my applications.  Now all my applications are gone.  I must have messed something up!  But there must be cron job to do it then eh?  I'll check there.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me

Comment: This will show "Restart is not available on Wayland" as of `gnome-shell-3.20`

Comment: -1, this doesn't work on Wayland, which is very common nowadays and cannot be ignored in the answer. The message is  "Restart is not available on Wayland" , as Ikraav already reported.

Answer (score 55):

From [Desktop entries](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_entries) in Arch linux wiki, this works on later versions of Gnome:

```
update-desktop-database ~/.local/share/applications
```

Comment: it's works on wayland GNOME

Comment: This is the correct way of doing it.

Comment: sometimes sudo is also needed

Comment: This also works for KDE

Answer (score 12):

Cross-posting this [from the Ubuntu question site](https://askubuntu.com/a/884758/13833).

You need to:

- Update the timestamp on the top-level icon directory
- Run `gtk-update-icon-cache`

Note: hicolor is the default theme which app developers should use. if you're making an icon theme, refresh your icon theme's folder instead.

```
sudo touch /usr/share/icons/hicolor ~/.local/share/icons/hicolor
sudo gtk-update-icon-cache
```

See (the only documentation I can find for this): https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Scriptlets#Icon_Cache

Comment: when running wayland, doing alt+f2, and then run "r" wont work. This saved me a lot of time. (otherwise have to logout and login again)

Comment: the "touch" trick saves my day!

Answer (score 12):

Please refer to the [XDG Desktop Menu Specification](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xdg-desktop-menu). To update the list of available desktop launchers in the Applications menu please run:

```
xdg-desktop-menu forceupdate
```

The update will be reflected in couple seconds.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're downvoted. This is the only thing that worked for me. I would note that it failed silently when I had errors in the Desktop Entry file, but once I had them fixed it worked fine.

Comment: Same here. It didn't refresh all I needed, but at least it allows me *some* control which literally none of the other answers gave (NixOs, Wayland + Gnome3)

Answer (score 1):

I tried a few ways, including these posted here, but none worked except this one

```
gnome-shell --replace & disown
```

Comment: Well.... this worked but it also pooched my Gnome. I got a 'Oh no! Something has gone wrong' message. But the desktop files were updated :-/

Comment: Nix + Wayland + Gnome3: `libmutter-Message: 21:22:48.638: Running GNOME Shell (using mutter 45.5) as a Wayland display server
Failed to setup: Could not take control: GDBus.Error:System.Error.EBUSY: Device or resource busy
`

Answer (score 1):

Tried all of the above. Only thing that worked in the end was logging out, and logging back in.

Sometimes it's the simple things that work best.

Comment: Appreciate this confirmation having reached the end of the list with no reprieve :)